# como posso utilizar group by junto do order by

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

como utilizar o `GROUP BY` junto com o `ORDER BY`? preciso ordenar minha `tabela` de forma `ASC` porem não consigo utilizando `GROUP BY` como devo fazer para utilizar os dois juntos?

trecho de código:

```
mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT nome_fotos, img, id_cliente FROM alboom WHERE id_fot = '$getid' GROUP BY id_cliente ORDER BY id ASC");
```

esse e meu código porem ele não ordena as fotos.

o resultado apos a consulta no workbench ficou

```
nome_fotos = merry
img = merry.jpg
id_cliente = 2
```

ou seja ele nao ordenou porque eu tenho o id = 1 no banco de dados.

Comment: Qual erro aparece?

Comment: nao da erro ele apenas nao mostra a imagem na ordem que eu quero

Comment: Quando você agrupa uma informação, você está ocultando tudo que se repete, no entanto, você não poderá "ver" outras informações destes registros agrupados, ou seja, não pode ter mais campos no `select` que no seu `group by`. Ele não vai funcionar. Um `order by` também não faz sentido dentro de uma subconsulta. Se não quer mostrar os repetidos, utilize o `distinct` e o para ordenar utilize o campo correto. Verifique se seu `WHERE` não está limitando a apenas um (1) registro sua consulta não diferenciando no ASC e DESC.

Comment: Qual o sentido de se utilizar a cláusula GROUP BY sem uma função de agregação? Não sei se foi apenas um erro de digitação mas você ordena por este campo id que não aparece em nenhum outro lugar do comando SELECT.

Comment: porque usar `group by` se a id_cliente não se repete?

Answer (score 1):

No comando `select` você informa todas as colunas que você está solicitando na sua consulta.  O que não estiver no `select` não faz parte da consulta.

Se no comando `select` você não solicitou o campo `id` então você não poderá utilizá-lo depois no comando `order by`.

Por isso sua consulta não funciona... você está solicitando um `order by` em uma coluna que não existe no resultado da consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Não testado, mas acredito que você pode separar a ordenação em um subselect:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT nome_fotos, img, id_cliente, id_fot FROM alboom 
         WHERE id_fot = '$getid' ORDER BY id_cliente ASC
) AS tabela GROUP BY id_cliente
```

Comment: nao funcionou continuou na mesma

Comment: testei assim: `mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT nome_fotos, img, id_cliente, id_fot FROM alboom 
         WHERE id_fot = '$getid' ORDER BY id_cliente ASC
) AS alboom GROUP BY id_cliente");`

Comment: Você deseja ordernar as fotos pelo id_cliente, certo? O subselect, somente ele funciona? Poderia anexar um print da saída com query executada?

Comment: e e meio dificil pois meu botao de print screen foi quebrado nao consigo printar a tela mas vou executar o comando no workbench e colo ele aqui pode ser?

Comment: Sim, edite a pergunta com o resultado que está obtendo.

Comment: ele sempre pega o primeiro id independente da clausula se eu colocar `ASC` ele pega a primeira linha se eu colocar `DESC` ele me retorna a mesma linha

Comment: na minha consulta que eu fiz com o codigo ele me retorna os dados do segundo `id` e nao do primeiro independente se for `ASC` ou `DESC`

Comment: editei a pergunta